# Large mySQL table: big table or multiple tables and a view?

Tags: mysql

I have a user profile table that has 32 fields. These fields are always updated and accessed at the same time. I'm wondering what's the better design, this 32 field-table or split the table into smaller tables and join through a view? Or even, it's possible that the best is split the big table and join it through a SELECT ... JOIN

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the fields are?  The proper approach depends on that.  I suspect that you should split into more tables and do JOINs.

Comment: It's data about users that can be easily categorized into: personal info, curriculum and personal view points

Comment: Hmmm....  What exactly is the problem your having?  Excessive locks because of 1 column updates?  I'm just wondering what the problem is that is being caused by horizontal size.

Comment: No, I don't have any problem (by now). I just want to be sure about my design because changing it now it's easier than wait until everything is working

Comment: Unless there's some compelling reason, I would leave it one table then.  I vaguely remember reading something a while back about when it would be a good idea to split a table horizontally in a situation such as yours, but I can't remember it.  Maybe I have the link saved somewhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is not hierarchial, it is of no use to split the table. Instead it will result an extra overhead while executing the joins. On the other hand if you have repetitions of records in this table, go ahead for a split. It will preform better.

Comment: Then keeping single table is feasible and correct. Do not consider splitting it. It wont bring out any extra benefit.